# How do I remove the background on this type of images when object color is very similar to the background?

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, image-recognition, scikit-image

I am working on removing the background of [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYxzi.jpg) where the object is the top the model is wearing. I have to do this on a range of images, some of them have very distinct background colors, some have very noisy/colorful backgrounds, and some are like this one where the background color and object color are very similar.

Right now, the process I'm taking is from image -> grayscale -> use otsu threshold to get black and white image -> canny edge detection -> opening and closing -> find contour -> overlay on original image

This works well with some of the images and doesn't work at all for others, like the one above. I don't know where to go from here and also have the one process automatically remove backgrounds for all the different images.

I'm using the opencv2-python, PIL, and scikit-image packages.

---

So I tried out grabcut and it works reasonably well. I ended up using the tutorial codes [here](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_grabcut/py_grabcut.html) and modified it slightly.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread(filename)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) #convert to RGB color
img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img,1,1,1,1,cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT,value= (0,255,255) #add thin border so images where foreground bleeds off page are not cut out
img = np.array(Image.fromarray(img).resize((200,200))) #make it run faster and standardize size of the img
mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2],np.uint8)

bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)

rect = (1,1,200,200)
cv2.grabCut(img,mask,rect,bgdModel,fgdModel,5,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)

mask2 = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
new_img = img.copy()
new_img[np.where((mask2==0))] = np.array([0,255,255]).astype('uint8') #this allows you to change the background color after grabcut
```

Comment: Your links to image points to the same image. Usually the first thing is to try is [grabcut](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d8/d83/tutorial_py_grabcut.html#gsc.tab=0). You don't need interaction with the user, you can simpy use the border as background, and the center of the image as foreground.

Comment: You should really update your question with the correct link for the second image.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, they were meant to be the same image...I just copied over the links.

Comment: Can't be done. Either trace these images by hand, or shoot them again [against a background that you actually stand a chance of being able to remove in software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key). White on white is a non-starter.